# hasClass and addClass not working for the dynamic content comes from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function that expose and hide html DIVs on the document  by add/remove the class 'hidden' from it ,  its look this this

```
function Expose (castid){
    if ( $('#newsitemcontent-' +castid).hasClass('hidden')){
        $('#newsitemcontent-' +castid).removeClass('hidden');                                            
        $('#broadcast-' +castid).addClass('ExposeNews');
    } else {                                            
        $('#newsitemcontent-' +castid).addClass('hidden');
        $('#newsitemcontent-' +castid).slideUp("fast");
        $('#broadcast-' +castid).removeClass('ExposeNews');
    }      

    return false;

}
```

This function is working fine with already printed DIVs which comes by default from php, but if any div is written using javascript such as that DIVs which written by

```
$(output).insertBefore('.broadcast:first').fadeIn('slow');
```

it will not run . I think the function cannot see the DIV ids for the DIVs that printed from javascript

the html which jquery print is for example

```
<div id="broadcast-1" class="broadcast news highlightedbroadcast" onclick="Expose(1)">
                <div class="newsitemtitle">
                    <a class="stopp" href="#" target="_blank" title="title">title</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="newsitemcontent-1>" class="newsitemcontent hidden">

                msg

            </div>
            <div class="newsitemcontentmisc">something will come here</div>
</div>
```

and the javascript is printing the html like this (it uses https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/blob/master/mustache.js fo render the text from hidden div content as a template)

```
    var solobroadcast_template =$("#hidden_solobroadcast").html()
    var convertedvars = {
                broadcasts_ids: this.castid,
                broadcasts_titles: this.casttitle,
                broadcasts_castmsgs: function (){
                    return contentmsg;
                }
            };
   var output = Mustache.render(solobroadcast_template, convertedvars);             
    $(output).insertBefore('.broadcast:first').fadeIn('slow');
```

the problem is that Expose function is working fine with already printed content but the problem if the page print a new code using javascript the Expose function will **WORK** but the hidden class with not added or removed.

any advice?

Comment: how is `Expose` invoked

Comment: I edit the code with them html

Comment: `setInterval(function(){Expose()}, 3000);`

Comment: add the ajax part and the part where you are actually inserting your nodes into the DOM, to your question.

Comment: edit with the code of javascript

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. Try it with on():

```
<div id="broadcast-1" class="broadcast news highlightedbroadcast" data-bc="1">

$('.broadcast').on('click', function() {
  Expose($(this).attr('id').split('-')[1]);
  // OR
  // Expose($(this).data('bc'));
});
```